# Regex number and dashes

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I would love to have a regex on my `LIKE` clause with the criteria given:

- It should **only** have 13 length characters
- First 8 characters should be number
- The 9th character should append a dash (`-`)
- The rest of 4 characters are the rest of the numbers.

*Example:*

- `12345678-9123`
- `98765432-1234`

Currently have this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_VALIDATE_ID](@TX_INPUT VARCHAR(50))RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN     
    DECLARE @bitInputVal AS BIT = 1
    DECLARE @InputText VARCHAR(50)

    SET @InputText = LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@TX_INPUT,'')))
  
    IF @InputText <> '' AND LEN(@InputText) = 13
    BEGIN
        SET @bitInputVal = CASE
                                WHEN @InputText LIKE '%^[0-9]%'  THEN 1
                            ELSE 0 
                            END
    END
  RETURN @bitInputVal
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need a UDF for this, as SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator can handle this requirement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
--                  \          8 digits              /  -  \   4 digits  /
```

Comment: Thanks, I first thought of this and thought there are still better option.  Anyway thank you.